# Install jquery.storage with bower

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bower

I would like to use the [jQuery Storage Plugin](http://www.jquerysdk.com/category/jquery.storage). I am using [Bower](http://bower.io) to install my dependencies. So I have the following `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "2.3.2",
      "jquery": "1.9"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to install jQuery Storage plugin (or any other jQuery Plugin) using bower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery Storage Plugin](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API) is not available in the [Bower Registry](http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/) so you can't simply run `bower install jQuery-Storage-Plugin`.

That being said the Plugin is Available on github over at [jQuery Storage Plugin](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API) which means you can run:

```
bower install julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API --save
```

Bower will install and save the jQuery Storage Plugin to your bower.json file.

Bower allows you to do shortname for github repos or you could type in the full git URL.

Here is the relevant snippet from the docs

> A remote Git endpoint, e.g., git://github.com/someone/some-package.git. Can be public or private. ‡
>
> A local Git endpoint, i.e., a folder that's a Git repository. ‡
>
> A shorthand endpoint, e.g., someone/some-package (defaults to GitHub). ‡